# Mongo: returning creation date in a record set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm querying mongodb using mongo shell.  I'm looking at the most recent 10 orders like this:

```
# Gets most recent orders:
db.orders.find().sort( {'_id': -1} ).limit(10)
```

I'd like to include an additional column in the output that is the creation date in human readable form.  I want to use getTimestamp() on the ObjectId.

Can i do this in a single query using a calculated field?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single query. The results will only contain the actual fields in the document. You can post-process it in the shell like this though;

```
var results = db.orders.find().sort( {'_id': -1} ).limit(10);

results.forEach(function(result){
  result.timestamp = result._id.getTimestamp();
});

printjson(results);
```